# R tryCatch neuralnet, unexpected output

Tags: r, neural-network, try-catch

I'm building a neural net for the Kaggle, "Ghost, Ghoul, Goblin" challenge.

I am sampling my (training) data X times (for illustration purposes X = 6) splitting it into a training and test set. I then run my neural net on each of the X (6) data sets and record the accuracy. I'm doing this so I can then compare the accuracy between different nets (one layer 3,4,5 hidden, two layers 3+3, 4+3 etc)

My neural net part of the code is

```
set.seed(26)
mysamples <- sapply(1:iterations, function(j) {
  temp <- sample(1:371, size = insamplesize, replace = F)
})

nn3results <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = iterations, nrow = 1))

myseed <- 0
for (nnloop in 1:iterations){
  myseed = myseed + 1
  set.seed(myseed)
  nn_idx <- mysamples[,nnloop]
  nn_rep_train <- mydata[nn_idx,]
  nn_rep_test <- mydata[-nn_idx,]
  nn_rep <- neuralnet(Ghost+Ghoul+Goblin ~ bone_N + rot_N + hair_N + soul_N, 
                      data=nn_rep_train, hidden=c(4))
  mypredict <- compute(nn_rep, nn_rep_test[,2:5])$net.result
  idx <- apply(mypredict, c(1), maxidx)
  nn_rep_test$Pred <- as.factor(c('Ghost', 'Ghoul', 'Goblin')[idx])
  print(paste("sim",nnloop,"=",round(sum(diag(table(nn_rep_test$type, nn_rep_test$Pred)))
          /outsamplesize,5),"%","myseed = ",myseed))
  nn3results[1,nnloop] <- sum(diag(table(nn_rep_test$type, nn_rep_test$Pred)))
}
```

Which performs exactly as I would expect, until iteration 5 where the neural net doesn't converge as follows

```
[1] "sim 1 = 0.74194 % myseed =  1"
[1] "sim 2 = 0.73118 % myseed =  2"
[1] "sim 3 = 0.75269 % myseed =  3"
[1] "sim 4 = 0.74194 % myseed =  4"
Error in nrow[w] * ncol[w] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: algorithm did not converge in 1 of 1 repetition(s) within the stepmax 
2: In is.na(weights) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

So not to worry. I have modified my code and put it inside `tryCatch` as follows.

```
myseed <- 0
for (nnloop in 1:iterations){
  myseed = myseed + 1
  set.seed(myseed)
  nn_idx <- mysamples[,nnloop]
  nn_rep_train <- mydata[nn_idx,]
  nn_rep_test <- mydata[-nn_idx,]
  tryCatch({
        nn_rep <- neuralnet(Ghost+Ghoul+Goblin ~ bone_N + rot_N + hair_N + soul_N, 
            data=nn_rep_train, hidden=c(4))
        },
       error = function(e){nn3results[1,nnloop] <- -1},
       warning = function(w){nn3results[1,nnloop] <- -1}, 
       finally={
          mypredict <- compute(nn_rep, nn_rep_test[,2:5])$net.result
          idx <- apply(mypredict, c(1), maxidx)
          nn_rep_test$Pred <- as.factor(c('Ghost', 'Ghoul', 'Goblin')[idx])
          print(paste("sim",nnloop,"=",round(sum(diag(
                table(nn_rep_test$type, nn_rep_test$Pred)))
                /outsamplesize,5),"%","myseed = ",myseed))
          nn3results[1,nnloop] <- sum(diag(table(nn_rep_test$type, nn_rep_test$Pred)))
  })
}
nn3results
```

Now the unexpected result. Since simulation 5 returns an error I would expect the corresponding `nn3results` to have a value of `-1` due to `error = function(e){nn3results[1,nnloop] <- -1}` but now the whole code seems to work, even for simulation 5, when previously it didn't.

```
[1] "sim 1 = 0.74194 % myseed =  1"
[1] "sim 2 = 0.73118 % myseed =  2"
[1] "sim 3 = 0.75269 % myseed =  3"
[1] "sim 4 = 0.74194 % myseed =  4"
[1] "sim 5 = 0.70968 % myseed =  5"
[1] "sim 6 = 0.75269 % myseed =  6"
> nn3results
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1 69 68 70 69 66 70
```

Seeds are the same. Results 1-4 are the same. Why does simulation 5 now work and not return -1?

As an aside any (constructive) code advice is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the finally statement is always executed when there is an error and when there is no error. Therefore, in this case, you are computing predictions using the model from the previous step (model 4). You should place the code that evaluates your model inside the tryCatch block.

The finally statement is often  used to ensure things are cleaned up. For example close a file. This should happen with or without an error.

Comment: Thanks Jan. You are right when I move the code from the `finally` section to the main `tryCatch expression` section, simulation 5 no longer has a result. Still surprisingly though, `nn3results[5]` is `0` and not `-1` as I would expect.

Comment: @SC. I don't have access to a computer to test, but I suspect you have to use the `<<-` operator instead of the `<-` operator as you are assigning to a variable in a higher scope from the error handling functions. Another common solution is to initialise the results to -1 as the first statement in the tryCatch block. In case of no error this is then overwritten later. You don't need the error handlers then (unless you want to flag the warnings)